# Iphone doesn't apply changes in the hosts file

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, hosts

I decided do jailbreak Iphone 6s ios 15.2 For my device, only the semi-tethered jailbreak from palera1n was suitable. After palera1n icon appeared, I decided change:  `/private/etc/hosts` file using filza using Webdav. For convenience, I changed the file: `master.passwd` and set the password for the root user. The changes worked. Now I can connect both via WinSCP and via Putty. My problem that no matter what sites I put in the hosts file, they are not applied, that is, both Safari and Firefox continue to open them, ignoring the hosts file. Here is the hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1 localhost
127.0.0.1   local
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
127.0.0.1   www.youtube.com
::1 www.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   m.youtube.com
::1 m.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   dzen.ru
::1 dzen.ru
```

Judging by this hosts file, Youtube and Zen shouldn't open, but they continue work. What could be the problem? Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about troubleshooting a Jailbroken iPhone. I do believe that jailbreaking and related subjects are off topic.

Comment: Hello. Then tell me where can I go to solve my problem?

Comment: A site that specializes in jailbreaking

Comment: @SteveChambers Questions about jailbroken devices are generally ok (https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/492/asking-jailbreak-related-question).

Comment: Steve Chambers, what forum or site can I ask a question to get an answer? 
I need specific addresses.

Comment: There is no StackExchange site specifically for jailbroken devices. If you are looking for other sites, please use your prefered search engine to look for one.

Comment: YouTube is not a good example of a domain that can be blocked with hosts.  Let's test something else to see if it's reading/resolving hosts from this file.  Add the IP of your router with a unique name.  Example `192.168.1.1      foobar`.  Now, try to reach your router with the host foobar.  If it can, things are working as they should.

Comment: My router address is: 192.168.1.254
I added it in hosts:
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1localhost.localdomain
255.255.255.255broadcasthost
::1 localhost
127.0.0.1 local
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
127.0.0.1www.youtube.com
::1 www.youtube.com
127.0.0.1m.youtube.com
::1 m.youtube.com
127.0.0.1 dzen.ru
::1 dzen.ru
192.168.1.254 foobar

Pings foobar and 192.168.1.254, but I can access the router using only on 192.168.1.254
Added to file hosts on the computer:
192.168.1.254 foobar
Exactly the same behaviour.